# HM10 Bluetooth (CC2541) put in to sleep while connected to iOS application

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-low-energy, iphone, power-consumption, sleep

I'm trying to trigger an action on iOS application using HM10 Bluetooth module. And i have successfully accomplished the functionality, But now my concern is the power consumption, I have already moved to the ATTiny85 controller chip and it wakesup using hardware interrupt. So ATTiny along consumes 0.2µA in sleep mode(Which is the 99% of time).

My question is how i put HM10 module in to sleep mode while its connected to my iOS application?

This whole module supposed to drive by using coin cell battery.

Any helpful tips are welcome..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you downvote any question, please mention the reason of it, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it to sleep with the command **AT+PWRM0**, and then wake it up sending a
long line of random alphabetic characters which is 80 characters or more. See here: [HM-10 as iBeacon](http://www.blueluminance.com/HM-10-as-iBeacon.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already enabled auto sleep mode in my module, But it doesn't seems to be sleeping after connected to central device(In my case iPhone). Any idea why?